# XLST collpases my <script> contents to one line as a result commenting out javascript!

Tags: xslt

**UPDATE:** Apologies all it was my http server stripping white space from from xslt before it was sent and was not aware of javascript comments (I should really del the question but cannot).

My XSLT looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:output
  method="xml"
  indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
      // ©2011

      function function(){
        // do stuff...
      }

    ]]></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p> blah blah... </p>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

But the resulting xml is always collapsed to one line resulting in my javascript being commented out from the inital comment! This happens is all major browsers! Despite indent="yes"..

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Tested in IE, FF and Opera (I don't have a web server right now to test with Chrome...)

Comment: Neither could I repro this -- tested with nine different XSLT processors -- see my answer.

Comment: It also works on Chrome and Safari. There could be problems if you are not encoding the source correctly in UTF-8, that's because the `©` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I couldn't repro this.**

**With all of the following nine XSLT processors** (MSXML3 included -- so in IE you should get a good result):

- MSXML (3, 4, 6)
- .NET (XslCompiledTransform and XslTransform)
- Altova (XML-SPY)
- Saxon 6.5.4
- Saxon 9.1.07 (XSLT 2.0 processor)
- XQSharp (XSLT 2.0 processor)

**when I perform the provided XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <xsl:output   method="xml"   indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
   <html>
    <head>
     <title>Title</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       <![CDATA[
              // ©2011
              function function()
              {
              // do stuff...
              }
         ]]>
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <p> blah blah... </p>
    </body>
   </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**on this XML document** (as no source XML document is provided in the question):

```
<root/>
```

**the result is the same:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

              // ©2011
              function function()
              {
              // do stuff...
              }

      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p> blah blah... </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Therefore, this is behavior of a buggy XSLT processor**, not on the above list -- or there is some missing data in the question.

Comment: My HTTP Server was stripping white space from the xslt file and was not javascript comment aware.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your javascript in `<xsl:text>` - Element instead of the CDATA Section. This will at least keep up your linebreaks you made inside. I'm not sure if CDATA stuff cares about linebreaks.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><xsl:text>
  // ©2011

  function function(){
    // do stuff...
  }

</xsl:text></script>
```

You also should try to to use `method=html` instead of xml because your generating html content.

In addition: i think the indent=yes stuff only applies to the indention of the XML Elements. I don't thin that mechanism cares about Text or CDATA Sections so you have to do the linebreaks yourself (as you already did in your javascript).

Comment: Sorry the problem was my http server, see update. I was generating xml - XHTML is an xml document in every sense.

Answer (score 0):

Three things to try:

1. You're generating HTML, so why have output method XML?
2. The `CDATA` will be used by the XML Parser on input for the XSLT engine, and not carried through (`CDATA`doesn't appear in the XML info model).
3. Would using `xml:space='preserve'` on the `script` element help?

Comment: 1) I was generating xml (XHTML), the whole point of CDATA is it is left as is, 3) nope. See update - it was my http server's fault.

Comment: @Fëanor re. CDATA: I think you misunderstand how the XML info-model works. CDATA is purely about encoding, once parsed it disappears (this is why there is no XSLT element to create CDATA).

Comment: yes it is not parsed but it is not dropped either - thats the point to pass it on as is

Comment: @Fëanor: That's an implementation choice from your XSLT process then.